# PocketBase re-authenticate user

Tags: flutter, dart, pocketbase

In PocketBase, let's say the token from
**/api/collections/users/auth-with-password** expires, how do you re-authenticate the user?

Auth collections has **/api/collections/users/auth-refresh** but it can only refresh authenticated users, right? So if the token is already expired and you use **auth-refresh**, it will not work, it will return **"The request requires valid record authorization token to be set."** , which doesn't make sense to me.

My current thoughts:

- When the user's token expires, log the user out and make them log in again? *(Counter Productive)*
- Save the password in local cache then check if the token is valid, then use the password again? *(Super Sketchy)*

**I am using the Dart SDK.**

Do you have any idea how to re-authenticate a user in PocketBase? Thank you.

Comment: Refreshing tokens should happen while previous token is still valid. Once a token expires, you should require user to relogin. So bullet 1 is the way to go with the addition of refreshing along the way before expiration.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the current user token in the authRefresh()

import 'package:pocketbase/pocketbase.dart';

final pb = PocketBase('YOUR POCKET BASE URL');

final authData = await pb.collection('users').authRefresh();

```
Requires record Authorization:TOKEN header
```

The constructor :
package:pocketbase/src/services/record_service.dart Future authRefresh({   String? expand,   String? fields,   Map<String, dynamic> body = const {},   Map<String, dynamic> query = const {},   **Map<String, String> headers = const {}**, })

Answer (score 0):

This problem happened to me and I solved the problem with all my research.
You can solve this problem by setting the value 0.95 to the **maxChildSize** property
and also in the ***showModalBottomSheet*** function
Set the **clipBehavior** property to **Clip.none**.

```
showModalBottomSheet(
  clipBehavior: Clip.none,
  builder: (context) => DraggableScrollableSheet(
  maxChildSize: 0.95
  )
)
```